# How can i show a state name instead of numeric value in label

Tags: asp.net, sql, repeater

I am using repeater in asp.net website, in this repeater i have labels in which i am showing data from database table.

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl_state" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("state") %>'></asp:Label>
```

here state data is state id which is numeric.

I have two tables in database 1.) register 2.) state
When i register product i save state id in register table for state.
and in state table i have state id and state name.

I am fetching data from register table so it is showing me state id.
But i want to bind state name instead of state id.

Comment: Difficult to tell without knowing your table structure... probably you just need to change the databinding in `Text='<%#Eval("state") %>'` but you also need to make sure that property is available at that point, hence the code you use to fetch the data will show whether you need to adapt that as well or not...

Comment: Please don't use Eval. Either use model binders or if you are using older version of .NET use the OnRow/ItemDatabound event to do the binding in code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your fetching query to

`SELECT R.*, S.name AS statename FROM register R LEFT JOIN state S ON R.state = S.id`

and use

`<asp:Label ID="lbl_state" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("statename") %>'></asp:Label>`

Comment: It works fine but I have one more question, if i have one more country table and similarly i want country name then how to integrate in this query.

Comment: just add new left join for the country table